# Selecting specific columns in a large database in Excel Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file, starting from A to GM .
In row 3, I have columns headings, as an example, as follows:

```html
Sub bar Sub Sim bar Sub IV bar
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 4
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 3 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 4 0 0 1 1 0 0
```

I have several column heading ( sub, bar, sim,...)
I want to select the columns with a specific heading column, say "bar" and see them in **sheet 2** as follows:

```html
bar bar bar
1 1 4
1 0 0
1 1 1
1 3 0
1 1 1
0 0 1
0 1 1
0 1 1
1 1 1
0 0 1
4 1 0
```

I know how to do it using vlookup and filter. However, I want to do using a simple VBA, if it is possible. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Sub main()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3") 'copy data from sheet1 to sheet2

    With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:GM3") 'reference sheet2 headings
        .Replace what:="bar", lookat:=xlWhole, replacement:="" ' replace wanted heading with blank
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide blank headings columns
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireColumn.Delete ' delete visible heading columns
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' unhide hidden columns
        .Value = "bar" 'write wanted heading back
    End With
End Sub
```

just change "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" to your actual sheet names

Comment: what line is throwing that message?

Comment: in the error message box click the "Debug" button and you'll be brought to the offending line

Comment: which line is highlighted?

Comment: if you meet an error and click "Debug", you must have a code line highlighted either yellow or blue

Comment: Does that window saying “No cells were found...” show a “Debug” button?

Comment: it must be syntax error try to copy paste again the code.

Comment: I just checked the error is related to the empty columns. I need to keep the empty columns. Are you able to help  @  DisplayName